# Layouts in Android [ id or field cannot be resolved]

Tags: android

```
public class Page1 extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = null;
                        myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Page1.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });          
    }

}
```

I want to load contents from another XML file named welcome.xml, but i do get an error `welcome cannot be resolved or is not a field`

This Page1.java class is next screen of my Android Application.

My Welcome.xml

```
<Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/welcome" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working.

If you don't set the handler, do you see the button in the screen?

Is the file actually named «**W**elcome.xml»? Try to remove the capital letter (rename it to welcome.xml). Then do a clean, rebuild and check if it works now...

Answer (score 1):

Could you paste your complete xml file and log? my first guess is you have a case issue , your layout file is named "Welcome" and you have setContentView to "welcome" . Also dont have same names for layouts and controls , it will get confusing.

Answer (score 1):

firend you are making silly mistake:see this

---

---

```
public class Page1 extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(**R.id.Button01**);//use id of button here not layout name

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = null;
                    myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Page1.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });          
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Is this all what your `welcome.xml` has?

Your button isn't under a layout. thus, the layout file itself will be throwing out exceptions.
secondly, `android:text` is not correct. the entry you have made there, should be under `android:id`

and it shouldn't be:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
```

but:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Welcome.xml contains Button with id welcome which is not an layout to setContentView 
Views can be List, relative, absolute  table etc .. in which you can add a button.

And also check for the Case in filename and specified R.layout.*******

Sample xml file with linearlayout and a button. Save it as welcome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearlayoutmain"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<Button
android:id="@+id/ButtonWelcome"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button"
>
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

in Your Code

```
public class Page1 extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonWelcome);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = null;

                **//You have called Page1.class again which is the name of this class //again** 
                        myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Page1.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });          
    }

}
```

Create another activity similarly and the call that class in the intent marked bold.

Answer (score 0):

Your Welcome.xml is not complete, should be something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/welcome" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, if your are still having problemas, **try to clean your project so the R.java get updated with new id values** like welcome id (R.id.welcome),because if R.java does not contain welcome id, you will get errors like that.